# In Current variation product weight not showing

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, product-weight

I have added weight to the product but weight is not displaying in grid section
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reindex indexers to get this value in the product grid as it is populated using flat tables. Reset all indices using;

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and reindex them using;

```
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

to get the value to be reflected in the grid.

Comment: I tried using command but still no result